# Looping through tabular CSV files doesn't return intended fields

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have a 20,000 line CSV file with this data:

| Location, | Light, | Proximity, | Ax, | Ay, | Az, | Gx, | Gy, | Gz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SidePocket | 2.0 | 0.0 | -1.1259307861328125 | -10.622817993164063 | 0.8393707275390625 | 0.7456817626953125 | -2.3446502685546875 | -0.6551361083984375 |
| HandBag | 2.0 | 0.0 | -1.1259307861328125 | -10.622817993164063 | 0.8393707275390625 | 0.8383636474609375 | -3.1872711181640625 | -0.064971923828125 |
| SidePocket | 2.0 | 0.0 | 0.5566253662109375 | -9.675201416015625 | 1.7905426025390625 | 0.8383636474609375 | -3.1872711181640625 | -0.064971923828125 |
| SidePocket | 2.0 | 0.0 | 0.5566253662109375 | -9.675201416015625 | 1.7905426025390625 | 0.170440673828125 | -2.976348876953125 | 0.05218505859375 |
| BackPocket | 2.0 | 0.0 | -0.3665771484375 | -9.739242553710938 | 2.12567138671875 | 0.170440673828125 | -2.976348876953125 | 0.05218505859375 |
| SidePocket | 2.0 | 0.0 | -0.3665771484375 | -9.739242553710938 | 2.12567138671875 | -0.1981201171875 | -1.846099853515625 | 0.290802001953125 |
| Ear | 2.0 | 0.0 | -0.490264892578125 | -9.91455078125 | 1.34954833984375 | -0.1981201171875 | -1.846099853515625 | 0.290802001953125 |

I want something to loop through all rows of a column based on the column header and do some computation. I tried using the CsvHelper library:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        textReader = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
    stringParse = new StringReader(textReader);
    txtOutput.Text = "";
}

private void btnParse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var csv = new CsvReader(stringParse);
    while( csv.Read() )
    {               
        var stringField = csv.GetField<string>( "Location" );
        txtOutput.Text += DoSomething(stringField.ToString()) + "\n";
    }
}
```

The problem I face are:

- Firstly, this is very, very slow. Halts my small WPF app.
- Secondly, it doesn't return the values for the intended field. It dumps the whole CSV file in the output.

Where have I made a mistake?

Here's how the actual CSV file looks:

```
Location, Light, Proximity, Ax, Ay, Az, Gx, Gy, Gz
"SidePocket" 2.0 0.0 -1.1259307861328125 -10.622817993164063 0.8393707275390625 0.7456817626953125 -2.3446502685546875 -0.6551361083984375
"HandBag" 2.0 0.0 -1.1259307861328125 -10.622817993164063 0.8393707275390625 0.8383636474609375 -3.1872711181640625 -0.064971923828125
"SidePocket" 2.0 0.0 0.5566253662109375 -9.675201416015625 1.7905426025390625 0.8383636474609375 -3.1872711181640625 -0.064971923828125
```

Comment: Why don't you give a try with the `Excel Interop libs`

Comment: @TheApache Didn't know something like that existed. Will have a look  now.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.regexr.com/3ea3m Hopefully it helps :)

Comment: @ProXicT How do I access vales based on headers? I am a regex novice!

Comment: On the website I've directed you to, you can simply hover over one of the lines and you can see each group, that way you can access values based on the header, every implementation can do that, just take a look at some regex implementation in C# (Not my language though)

Comment: For example, take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) approach.

Comment: @TheApache Dear God, no. Excel Interop? I couldn't think of a slower way to do this in common use, and he already had performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no problem reading a csv file of 4 times the size of your 20,000 lines in under 2 seconds. I don't know what is happening in `DoSomething` so that might be your next call of investigation.

I have made the following changes to address the two issues you describe.

First: use a `StringBuilder` to prevent the creation and discarding of lots of strings in your loop.

Second: Set the `Delimiter` in the `Configuration` object of the CsvHelper to a Space but do include the comma of your header field name in that case:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
using(var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(@"csv-test.txt")))
{
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter=" "; // space

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (csv.Read())
    {
        var stringField = csv.GetField<string>("Location,"); // the comma is relevant
        // or use sb.AppendFormat("{0}\n", DoSomething(stringField));
        sb.AppendLine(stringField);
    }
    txtOutput.Text = sb.ToString();
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

For 102,000 lines above code runs on my box in 1,7 seconds.

Comment: @rene It's not the `DoSomething()` as much as the `+=` doing repeated string concatenation on values big enough to soon hit the Large Object Heap. The good news is, with that in mind, the `StringBuilder` suggestion here is a good solution.